# How to determine URL has valid domain or not or it's a valid url?

Tags: android

What i get in android native messaging, whenever we send a message to some one and in the text there is a url, android recognizes that and underlined it showing it as a link, it does that for many domains, like .us,.uk,.dk,.ch and all others valid.
Even we send jhjh.us without 'www' or 'http' it recognises it as link.
and if the domain is wrong it doesn't do any thing.

I want the same thing, I tried using pattern

```
(((https?|ftp|file)://)|(www\\.))"+ "[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]
```

it does a good but in domain it didn't help. Also tried using `URLUtil.isValidUrl()` but of no use,
Can anyone give me some idea regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
public boolean isURL(String url)
{
        try {
            new URL(url);
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

U can use the Use UrlValidator to validate the URL 
Considering you are using [Class UrlValidator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html)

```
 UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
 urlValidator.isValid("http://Test Link!");
```

There are several properties that you can set to control how this class behaves, by default `http`, `https`, and `ftp` are accepted.